# OnPostExecute result null

Tags: java, android

I'm sending some data from my app to an external server.

```
public class PostKey extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Log.d(String.valueOf(result), " Result?");
        delegate.processFinish(result); // Returns NullPointerException
    }

    public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost     = new HttpPost("http://domain.com/post.php");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hoi", "test"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            Log.d(responseStr, "");
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }

    public interface AsyncResponse {
        void processFinish(String output);
    }
}
```

`Log.d(responseStr, "");` does return true or false, depending on what data was send, and logs it.

`delegate.processFinish(result);` returns the NullPointerException also mentioning `public class PostKey extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>` eventhough all the parameters are declared as `Strings`.

I've also tried replacing `result` with `responseStr` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Your activity implements the interface?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes, it does

Comment: You return null from doInBackground method so you get null in onPostExecute

Comment: You can pass the same to the constructor of asynctask and do `delegate= (AsyncResponse) activity;` Note : Activity implements the interface.

Comment: `void postData` => `String postData`, `Log.d(responseStr, "");` => `return responseStr` (also add `return null;` at the end of this method), body of `doInBackground` => `return postData(params[0]);` ... add null check in `onPostExecute` ... still `delegate` can be null if you do not set it ...

Comment: ... but still ... possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @sanatshukla there has to be a retun statement there, otherwise an error displays. With what could I replace it? Just `return;` isn't valid either

Comment: onPostExecute get the data return by doInBackground method. So, if you return it a null then you get null in onPostExecute.

Comment: you can check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your method call `delegate.processFinish(result);` 
delegate is not initialized. So you are calling a method on null object.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to that

```
public class PostKey extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    public PostKey(AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        delegate = asyncResponse;
    }   

    @Override 
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return postData(params[0]);
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Log.d(String.valueOf(result), " Result?");
        delegate.processFinish(result);
    } 

    public String postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost     = new HttpPost("http://domain.com/post.php");

        try { 
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hoi", "test"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            Log.d(responseStr, "");
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        } 
        return responseStr;
    } 

    public interface AsyncResponse { 
        void processFinish(String output);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result of postData() then change the return type of postData() from void to String and return that result to onPostExecute like this :

```
public class PostKey extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return postData(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Log.d(String.valueOf(result), " Result?");
        delegate.processFinish(result); // Returns NullPointerException
    }

    public String postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost     = new HttpPost("http://domain.com/post.php");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hoi", "test"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            return responseStr;
            Log.d(responseStr, "");
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
       return null;
    }

    public interface AsyncResponse {
        void processFinish(String output);
    }
}
```